# Referring to a figure

Tags: redundancy

I’m writing a paper that has a number of figures that compare two images, and I’m constantly debating whether it’s necessary to repeat the figure number when I compare those images in the text.

For instance, if I write “the object on the right in Figure 1 is an abstract version of the object on the left,” is it necessary to write “on the left in Figure 1,” “in that figure,” or “in the same figure?” Or is it obvious that I’m talking about Figure 1?

Comment: This is a style issue that borders on writing advice, and the context in which the references appear is a major variable. Still, I have found as a general rule that opening a sentence with "In Figure X, ..." does the clearest job of indicating that everything that follows involves the named figure, without my having to repeat the word _figure_. Thus, in your example, you might write "In Figure 1, the object on the right is an abstract version of the object on the left." To my eye and ear, it is unambiguous that the entire sentence refers to elements in Figure 1.

Comment: That works! Thank you.

Comment: "For instance, if I write “the object on the right in Figure 1 is an abstract version of the object on the left,”" I would use a possessive adjective: "on its left"

Comment: It **is customary** to write out Figure 1, Figure 2,  But you needn't repeat it. Unless you change figures.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could rephrase it to

Referring to Figure 1, the object on the right is the abstract version of the left side.

Comment: Another good alternative. Thanks

Comment: Or maybe: _Of the two objects in Figure 1, the one on the left is an abstract version of the one on the right._